# Guice annotatedWith for interface with Generics

Tags: guice

I have an interface TestInterface<U,V> that has many implementations, when I use Guice for binding I get a message saying TestInterface<Impl1, Impl2> not bound to an implementation. Following is the syntax I am using to bind interface with its implementations.

bind(TestInterface.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("Impl1Test")).to(Impl1.class);

p.s. I tested with a dummy interface but without generics and it worked fine, I reckon for generics something special needs to be done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When binding generic types, you need to use a `TypeLiteral` rather than the raw `class`. Otherwise, Guice wouldn't be able to distinguish between the generic types. In your case, it would look something like this:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<TestInterface<Impl1, Impl2>>(){})
    .annotatedWith(Names.named("Impl1Test"))
    .to(Impl1.class);
```

You may not even need the `annotatedWith` if you don't have other things that you want to bind as `TestInterface<Impl1, Impl2>`. Note the `{}` in the creation of the `TypeLiteral`... an anonymous subclass of `TypeLiteral` is necessary in order to have the generic type information preserved.